# trouble accessing multi index column after join

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I created the following multi-index column:

```
Out[213]:
    KEY POLL
        count   mean    sum
0   1   21  0.80921     10  
1   2   3   0.666667    2
2   3   67  0.835821    3
3   4   13  1.000000    4
4   5   674 0.876855    5
```

I can access the POLL multi-index column if i need to:

```
session_counts_merged[('POLL','sum')].head()
Out[225]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
Name: (POLL, sum), dtype: int64
```

However when I join the above table with another one, I can't figure out how to access the table anymore.

Here is the .info() on the new table:

```
account_aggregates.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9713 entries, 0 to 9712
Data columns (total 6 columns):
NATIVEACCOUNTKEY           9713 non-null int64
(NATIVEACCOUNTKEY, )       9713 non-null int64
(POLL, count)              9713 non-null int64
(POLL, mean)               9713 non-null float64
(POLL, sum)                9713 non-null int64
session_deciles            9713 non-null object
```

How can i access the column named (POLL, sum)?  Doing something like this:

```
account_aggregates_grouped['(POLL, sum)'].head()
```

results in a key not found error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'(POLL, sum)'` is a string.
`('POLL','sum')` is a tuple containing two strings.
A DataFrame with a MultiIndex has keys which are *tuples* composed of a label
from each index level. Therefore, change

```
account_aggregates_grouped['(POLL, sum)'].head()
```

to

```
account_aggregates_grouped[('POLL', 'sum')].head()
```